# Windows Service Increasing HIGH Cpu Usage

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I have created a *windows service* that would save data from *Biometrics* to Database.

I Used *Mysql* as the database then *ZKTeco* as *Biometrics*. To get the data from biometrics i used the *dll*. but, the main problem is that the service increase its HIGH CPU usage from `0.01%` to `30-50%` and wont drop unless i press stop then run again.

I have tried to put `thread.sleep` wherein most= of the cases its the solution but doesn't solve mine , i use `backgroundworker` since it minimize the cpu usage rather than using timer.

how can i solve or fix the HIGH Cpu? i Tried `thread.sleep(5000` 5seconds, `thread.sleep(1000)` 1second and lastly `thread.sleep(10)` nothing worked

```
 private void sendata()
    {
        try
        {
            //fetch db parameter by inifile
            _Host = _inifile.ReadSetting("Database Connection", "Host", 5000, "");
            _User = _inifile.ReadSetting("Database Connection", "User", 5000, "");
            _Port = _inifile.ReadSetting("Database Connection", "DBPort", 5000, "");
            _DBname = _inifile.ReadSetting("Database Connection", "Name", 5000, "");

            //Data from Biometric
            ICollection<MachineInfo> lstMachineInfo = manipulator.GetLogData(objZkeeper, int.Parse(MachineNo));

            //MySQL Connection
            connectionString = @"server=" + _Host + @";user id=" + _User + @";port=" + _Port + @";password=hj^yr490Tweh@ty4;database=" + _DBname + @";Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=100;";

            //Connection Starts
            using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                con.Open();
                var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                var cmdid = con.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText ="set foreign_key_checks=0;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `z_log`(`log_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,`machine_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,`subscription` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,`branch_id` VARCHAR(50),`user_id` VARCHAR(50),`datetime` VARCHAR(255),`checktype` VARCHAR(50),`accesstoken` VARCHAR(50),`status` VARCHAR(50) ,PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),UNIQUE(`datetime`))ENGINE =INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='List of ID type'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                //Get todays data
                var result = lstMachineInfo.ToList().Where(a => a.datetime > DateTime.Now).ToList();

                //fetch todays data
                foreach (var data in result)
                {
                    //Check last id
                    cmdid.CommandText =
                        "SELECT IF(COUNT(*)=0,0,(SELECT log_id FROM `z_log` ORDER BY log_id DESC LIMIT 1)) AS `ID` FROM z_log;";
                    var drd = cmdid.ExecuteReader();
                    while (drd.Read())
                    {
                        counts = Convert.ToInt32(drd["ID"].ToString()) + 1;
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                    drd.Close();

                   //save data where userid & datetime are not duplicate
                    string inserquery =
                        "INSERT IGNORE Into z_log(log_id,machine_id,subscription,branch_id,user_id,datetime,checktype,accesstoken,status)VALUES(" +
                        "@logid,@id,@subs,@branch,@user,@date,@check,@token,@status);";


                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(inserquery, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logid", counts);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", data.MachineNumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subs", Subscription.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branch", BranchID.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", data.IndRegID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", data.DateTimeRecord);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@check", data.InOut);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@token", AccessToken.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "0");
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                con.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Errorlogs(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

//Onstart
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
      {
         ReadIni();
         ZKBack.RunWorkerAsync();
      }

//Do Work
private void ZKBack_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {   
            //If device is not connected will connect
            if (isDeviceConnected == false)
            {
                Connect();

            }
            //if connected will get data
            else
            {
                sendata();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Errorlogs(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

 private void ZKBack_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        ZKBack.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: the windows service is literally getting the data from biometric then save it to database . the code above is the main brain which gets the data then get todays data by linq then fetch the linq save it after into the database it will loop and loop since its services

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(10);` is a problem. If you want the thread to yield CPU time, use `Sleep(0);`. You're looping far too fast, which eats CPU.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish here? Running this data process on an interval? BTW, I've used timers and I don't find they use a lot of CPU.  I wonder if you're creating a cyclical pattern here by running RunWorkerAsync in the RunWorkerCompleted event.  I'd also get rid of those Thread.Sleep(s).

```
private void ZKBack_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    ZKBack.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: i used timer before which uses too much cpu usage for me which hits 80%-100% usage all the time , the time i use background worker it decreased which hits 1%-30% .the thread is for looping . sorry still new to windows service